# Create an Array of NSDates like in Ruby

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to create an array of NSDates starting from today to next month. This can easily be done in Ruby using `Time.now..(Time.now + 30.days)`

How can I create an array of dates just like in Ruby in Objective C?

Comment: The answer to that question is only part of the answer to this one. The date calculation part of this question is important, and harder to figure out than the semantics of creating an array from a range of numbers.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen True - retracted.

Answer (score 5):

Any ObjC solution is unfortunately going to be far more verbose than that Ruby code.

The correct way to make the calculation is with `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSMutableArray * dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * plusDays = [NSDateComponents new];
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
for( NSUInteger day = 0; day < NUMDAYS; day++ ){
    [plusDays setDay:day];
    [dateArray addObject:[cal dateByAddingComponents:plusDays toDate:now options:0]];
}
```

To make the procedure more convenient (if you need to do it more than a few times), you could put this loop into a category method on `NSCalendar`, with `NUMDAYS` replaced with the argument and substituting `self` for `cal`.

Comment: The nice thing about this solution vs some of the others is that it avoids compounded error. i.e. instead of adding one day, thirty times, it adds one day to now, then adds two days to now, and so on. There are cases where that will produce better results.

Comment: Intriguing. Your statement makes me want to go hunting for such cases, @Catfish_Man.

Comment: Try something like calculating successive 2AMs in a US locale (or midnights in a Brazilian locale) across a DST transition. I think all the days after the transition should be off.

Answer (score 2):

After much downvoting and commenting, here's my REVISED answer...

```
-(NSDate *)nextDayFromDate:(NSDate *)originalDate {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [NSDateComponents new];
    dateComponent.day = 1;
    NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponent toDate:originalDate options:0];
    return tomorrow;
}

NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
[dateArray addObject:now];
for (int i=0;i<31;i++) {
    NSDate *firstDate = [dateArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDate *newDate = [self nextDayFromDate:firstDate];
    [dateArray addObject:newDate];
}
```

What this does is use the NSCalendar API to add a "day interval" to any given NSDate. Add "Now" to the array, then do a loop 30 times, each time using the previous NSDate object as input to the logic.

Comment: I think this falls out of that scope. You're handing the system a time interval, and it's spitting out a new date object. If "now==Feb 28th,  leap year", then the system will know that "tomorrow=Feb 29th" and not "March 1st"

Comment: But you're not asking the system for "tomorrow". You're asking the system for a date 86,400 seconds after now, which may well be the same calendar day (or skip one!).

Comment: I see...makes sense. ok, well let's modify the loop to instead ask for "now == today, give me tomorrow. tomorrow = now, give me next day. next day == now, give me next day...

Comment: That's a nice thought, but you'll quickly find that date calculations are really hard because of the many edge cases out there. You're better off using the right API to handle this stuff.

Comment: honestly, who is downvoting all the answers in this question thread?

Comment: Yep, matches mine pretty closely now.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in to do this quite as concisely as the Ruby you've posted. Breaking the problem down, you need a way to get the day after a particular date. Here's a function that will do that:

```
NSDate *CalendarDayAfterDate(NSDate *date)
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.day = 1;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
}
```

Next, you need to get an array of days one after the other:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:today];
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<30; i++) {
    NSDate *tomorrow = CalendarDayAfterDate(today);
    [dates addObject:tomorrow];
    today = tomorrow;
}
```

Comment: That's nice of you Josh :). Even the answer fixed to match mine after I commented on it has more upvotes. Oh well...